# Apache logs accesses on an already rotated log file

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I usually create my access and error logs in a domain-name folder under `/var/log`, and these files are rotated with logrotate using this conf :

```
/var/log/mydomain.org/access.log
{
  weekly
  missingok
  rotate 52
  compress
  delaycompress
  notifempty
  create 640 root adm
  sharedscripts
  prerotate
      /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -update -config=mydomain.org &> /dev/null
  endscript
  postrotate
      if [ -f /var/run/apache2.pid ]; then
          /etc/init.d/apache2 restart > /dev/null
      fi
  endscript
}
```

I have regularly this problem : my `access.log` is rotated to `access.log.1`, but apache2 keeps on logging access on `access.log.1`.

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double check that the postrotate part gets correctly executed (don't redirect to /dev/null but to some file you can check!).

Comment: Does it keep logging into the old file indefinitily?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `logrotate --debug /etc/logrotate.d/YOURFILE`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you're apache process is not putting a pid file in "/var/run/apache2.pid" and therefore your postrotate never executes.
While troubleshooting (as faker's comment suggests) maybe try this:

`...

   postrotate

          /etc/init.d/apache2 restart > /tmp/apache_restart.txt

    endscript

    }`

Then tomorrow look at /tmp/apache_restart.txt with `more /tmp/apache_restart.txt`

Answer (score -1):

Why would you use logrotate to rotate apache logs, when you could have it all on one simple directive?

You could use something like  something like:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/logs/httpd/error_log 86400"
```

This way you wont't need to handle the locks on the files, and apache would rotate the logs for you.

Comment: `LogRotate` is a perfectly valid way to handle Apache log rotation, and is in line with how many other Linux software do log rotation.  To improve your answer, please reword your answer to be friendlier and provide reasons why jpicaude should your solution instead of what he has already.